# Grammar まるで - ようだ

Tags: grammar

I have been taught that to use まるで, you must put ようだ or ように in the sentence. However, in the following sentence :

> まるで・・・尋問だね。

The "よう" part is missing, why is that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

まるで doesn't necessarily have to be used with ようだ. Saying `まるで + noun + だ/です` is totally fine. The following sentences are all valid and mean roughly the same thing.

- まるで尋問だ。
- まるで尋問のようだ。
- まるで尋問みたいだ。
- 尋問のようだ。
- 尋問みたいだ。

さながら is a literary word that works in the same way. (e.g., さながら尋問だ。)

Additionally, まるで means "at all" if used with a *negative* expression:

- その帽子は、私にまるで似合わない。
- 車が故障してしまい、まるで動かない。

Answer (score 0):

He meant

- まるで尋問だね。 = This is a torture, isn't it?

It's a different expression

- まるで尋問みたい/ようだね。 = It looks like a torture.